# Coulomb's law and its application

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law

I just read that Coulomb*s Law describes

(a) the forces that bind atoms together to form molecules

(b) the forces that bind molecules together to form solids.

My question is

Do a proton share its attractive force with two or more electrons or vice versa?

Comment: Hi Abir. [Neutral atoms can form chemical bonds with each other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_bond). However a discussion of chemical bonding is broad a question to be usefully answered here, and in case case it would be better discussed on the [Chemistry Stack Exchange](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem#Effect_on_physics

Comment: @JohnRennie I can't believe that you're willing to leave quantum mechanics and empty orbitals to the chemists!! Most of the quantum chemists I know are physicists at heart. :)

Comment: While I believe that this is indeed rather physics than chemistry, I do think the question is too broad, because the three questions are not the same. You might want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force to see that neutral objects can have attractive forces.